# filehandle.read() generating null characters in destination file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to read "src.txt" and copy it to "des.txt".I got it working 2 ways and both are producing pretty much the same result.

When I try the below code at end of the des.txt file I get weird characters. (all the data of "src.txt" is being copied successfully)

```
// Producing weird characters in the des.txt file at the end

  let readhandle = await fs.open("src.txt", "r");
  let writehandle = await fs.open("des.txt", "w");
  let bytesread = -1;
  while (bytesread != 0) {
    let data = await readhandle.read(); //default = 16384
    bytesread = data.bytesRead;
    writehandle.write(data.buffer);
  }
```

on the other hand, if I try this I get no extra weird characters

```
  let readhandle = await fs.open("src.txt", "r");
  let writehandle = await fs.open("des.txt", "w");

  let buffer = Buffer.alloc(16384);
  let stats = await readhandle.stat();
  let itrs = stats.size / 16384;
  for (let i = 0; i < itrs; i++) {
     let data = await readhandle.read(buffer, 0, 16384, null);
     writehandle.write(data.buffer);
  }
```

Why am I getting weird characters at end of des.txt with the first method but not with the second?

I tried using buffers of different sizes in the second method but the result is the same.